# SXA default redirect rule not working

Tags: sxa

I am trying the sxa default redirect url but it is not working for my site.
Steps followed : 
`/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Settings/Redirects/TestRedirect`

[image]

It is not redirecting me to the link i provided. Instead its opening the same URL which i am requesting.

Please help me resolve the issue.

Thanks all.

Comment: Ensure that your regex is fine and is matching correct URLs.

Comment: Remove the `/` after `^`: try `^ind/en/deu/$`

Comment: We have different countries as site. Some of them are not live, but they are visible on the dropdown in home page. We want that if user selects that country, instead of showing page not found it should redirect to some old site. It is not happening with the regex mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your comment:

> [image]

I understand that you have an item which actually matches that url but you don't want to show it and want to redirect instead, correct?

It won't work.

SXA redirect maps only work when item cannot be resolved from the url.

Try changing it temporarily to a url which cannot be resolve (just add few letters at the end of your regex) and it will work.

If you want to do redirect for an item which does exist, you either use `Redirect` items or better use II Rewrite module.

Comment: Thanks Marek. It worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should check (just my learnings from a few tests):

- does the old url match an existing page? (if so, it will use that and not redirect)
- skip any language in the old url

If that is all ok, it should redirect (the `^/` and `/$` are needed if you want regex - not sure if you do here)

ps: I don't think the external url will work though, but it should still redirect (to a faulty url in that case)

Comment: We have country code and language code as url. /bgd/en/aus/ . How to skip the en in the middle? Please help.

Comment: If it is in the middle, it's probably not Sitecore who is putting it there so you should keep the entire url. Was a bit of trial & error for me too..  but if you need to redirect to an external site, I think this will not be your solution for the redirect as external ones did not work for me.

Comment: Sxa default redirect wont work in this case? Do we need to use IIS redirect?

Comment: I think so - maybe someone from the SXA team can confirm to be sure...